# "I have a dream that" vs "I have a dream to"

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-choice

I have a dream to go to Las Vegas and I want to tell this to my friend but I am a little confused what is the right way to tell her about that.

Should I say that

> **I have a dream to go** to Las Vegas

or should I say

> **I have a dream that** one day I will go to Las Vegas.

Which one sounds more idiomatic? Is there any other way of saying the same thing but in a more native way?

Answer (score 1):

Both sound perfectly fine to me! I would probably lean towards "... to go to Las Vegas" for the sake of brevity in most conversations.

One note I would make, however, is that "I have a dream to go to Las Vegas" feels like it would probably happen sooner than "I have a dream that one day I will go to Las Vegas."

In other words, it's up to you.